# How to connect googleapiclient to cloud

Tags: android, google-api-client

How should I connect Google API client to network . The Google API client is actually failing with network error. As I can see this in logcat.

> beginFailureResolution for ConnectionResult{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR,
>   resolution=null, message=null}